# How to check if a string contains a substring - mysql

Tags: php, mysql

In my table I have a column that contains a random values.
They have a regular structure like below :

> ```
> id    | value
> ----------------  
> 1 | 1_426_7894(245)
> 2 | 4_463_9654(465)
> 3 | 3_954_3678(465)
> 4 | 9_356_5412(157)
> 5 | 5_986_3578(987)
> 6 | 2_125_4689(749)
> 7 | 8_286_7859(879)
> ```
>
> value1_value2_**value3**(value4)

now,I would like to search in this table where **value3** is 3678.
Is it possible to make this query ? or PHP should help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from thetable where mid(value, 7, 4) = 3678
```

Answer (score 0):

use `WHERE field LIKE %_value3`. The `%` matches anything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like that ?

```
DECLARE @variable varchar(max)
SET @variable = '3678'
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE variable1 like '%_' + '%_'+ @variable + '(%)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Search table where value3 is 3678

```
select * from
table_name
where INSTR(value,concat("_",3678,"(")>0;
```